# Best practices when Integrating an ASPX User control into a web form

Tags: asp.net, .net, telerik, ascx

I have a dashboard that I've created for an MVC .net web app that is using Telerik tools. The concept I'm attempting to achieve is to have a master dashboard page, that users can add tabs to, each tab holding a set of dashboard controls. The dashboard controls are currently in a user control file (ie. Dashboard.aspx and DashboardContent.ascx). One iteration of the dashboard controls works great, but when I programmatically add a new tab with the same user control the 2nd tab of controls does not work. I think I'm missing the concept here, and possibly completely approaching this from the wrong direction. Hoping someone can give me some suggestions on how to handle this type of situation correctly.

Many Thanks.